# Save JPA Repository where "other attribute"

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot.

When execute

oneJpaRepository.save(object) if no  Primary Key exist this object saves it, if it does exist, this updates the object.

How do I update this object through another attribute that is not the Primary Key? for example
oneJpaRepository.saveByCodigo(Object)

Note: I have already created a function updateObjectByOtherAtributte and it works, but I want to know if there is a way to do it through the

```
@Transactional
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query("UPDATE Concepto c SET c.idBui = :#{#concepto.getIdBui()}," +
    "c.descripcion = :#{#concepto.getDescripcion()}," +
    "c.admiteReglas = :#{#concepto.getAdmiteReglas()}," +
    "c.tieneCantidadFija = :#{#concepto.getTieneCantidadFija()}," +
    "c.tieneValorFijo = :#{#concepto.getTieneValorFijo()}," +
    "c.vigencia = :#{#concepto.getVigencia()}," +
    "c.valor = :#{#concepto.getValor()}, " +
    "c.detalles = :#{#concepto.getDetalles()}" +
    " WHERE c.codigo = :#{#concepto.getCodigo()}")
int updateConcepto(@Param("concepto") Concepto concepto);

int resultadoUpdate = conceptoJpaRepository.updateConcepto(concepto);

  if (resultadoUpdate == 0){ conceptoJpaRepository.save(concepto)
```

Comment: Please provide some of your code that you have already done.

Comment: i edit answer .

Answer (score 0):

The object will be updated if you do a modification in one attribute while the object is inside a transaction context.

You don't need to call oneJpaRepository.save() to update the object, you only need to modify the object inside a transaction

Typically in spring applications you have a layer service where the transaction are declared, inside this layer you can retrieve an object and set the new values. It is something like this

```
@Transactional
void serviceMethod (Object c){

    Object bd = oneJpaRepository.findById(c.id)
    bd.setFoo(c.getFoo)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is NOT necessary to call save on an object when using JPA a your persistence mechanism where the change you're wishing to save was made is inside a transaction (change was made after a tranasaction start and before a transacton end).

This is due a behaviour of JPA called [Transparent Persistence](http://www.copypasteisforword.com/notes/hibernate-transparent-persistence).

The save method when using Spring Data JPA will however ascertain whether the object is new or not and if new it will make the object persistent (i.e. create it on the database).